# Java throws java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, file, netbeans

My application throws exception - java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path.  Not sure why.  'message' variable is a string that contains the name of my sub folder, which is inside 'ServerFolder'.

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("C:\\ServerFolder\\" + message +  "\\" + " " + todaysDate + ".txt"), "utf-8"));
```

Comment: Why is the space in between? Is it expected ?

Comment: Can you add the OS folder path as well ?

Comment: I put that there for testing purposes, just to check if that was missing.  But no luck either way, even if i remove it.

Comment: This is the OS path - 'C:\ServerFolder\Joe'.  Message variable contains Joe.  It's a username.  I tried printing out message and it does display 'Joe'.

Comment: why are you suffxing todaysDate ?

Comment: @javaguy, not sure exactly what you mean but todaysDate is a string with a date that I wish to name my file.

Comment: What is the value of `todaysDate`? Does it contain a colon, or a slash (which are not allowed in file names)? E.g. `1970-01-01 00:00`, or `01/01/1970`?

Comment: TodaysDate is " Mon, Nov 7, '16 "
Without the double quote marks. Have a feeling this could be where the error lies..?

Comment: No, this value should be fine... Pls check that the _directory_ exists and the Java process has permissions to write into it.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the help.  I'll go mess around with it and hopefully find a solution.  Am looking at my directory as we speak and it's there but not 100% sure why java can't seem to find it.

Comment: Got it fixed! Silly mistake.  'Message' string had a space after it's name, so i used trim() and it worked.  Thanks for all the help once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiation of **FileOutputStream** is throwing the *FileNotFoundException*. Ensure that the path that you are passing in the String to **FileOutputStream** constructor is valid and you have permissions to create files in the directory.

Comment: I definitely have permission, I created the folders myself and added random files.  I am thinking it's the path but I do not seem to see where the error lies.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to make the SPACE character as the first character of your file name!

`new FileOutputStream("C:\\ServerFolder\\" + message +  "\\" + " " + todaysDate + ".txt")`

Comment: It is not clear whether your application is launched always under your login (in which case it should have permission to create the file) or whether it gets launched under a different login (in which case that login may not have the write permissions).